# How do I use an image Hot Spot in C#?

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to use Hot Spots in C# to detect a mouse click on a betting table.

Comment: is this in a web app or winform?  details, details!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define a "hot spot" with the following:

- Two points defining the upper-left and lower-right of a "bounding box"
- An offset defining the location of the upper-left of the bounding box as it relates to the farthest upper-left point of your image

If this is a Windows Forms app, you should be able to use a transparent image to "highlight" the area when the user mouses over it.  There are other techniques for this in web application using javascript.